# PHP Extracting words from a string

Tags: php, string

In PHP I have a string like this:

```
$string = "frame= 7840 fps= 53 q=0.0 size=  651693kB time=00:04:19.99 bitrate=20533.9kbits/s eta=00:00:22.63"
```

I need to extract the number 7840 into its own string. The problem is the number 7840 can be any number, like 1 or 2034321. The point is, whatever number is after frame=  needs to be extracted to its own string. In PHP how would I accomplish this?

Comment: This is a trivial regular expression, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

If it's really only that number you're after and the string always starts with `"frame="` you can simply clip the string from that point onwards by using an `(int)` typecast like this:

```
echo (int)substr($string, 6); // 7840
```

If there's any kind of variation in the beginning of your string I would highly recommend using regular expressions instead, which is already provided in other answers.

Comment: Won't `substr($string, 6)` just cut off the first 6 characters of the string? You need to provide a third length parameter, but then you can't have numbers of differing length

Comment: @Bojangles No, you don't. The string is effectively clipped by the typecast; if you're not sure, just try it :)

Comment: @Bojangles it's correct, because the (int) cast cuts off everything else...

Comment: Oh I see, that's quite a neat trick. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

here is regex the right tool:

```
if (preg_match("#frame=\s*(\d+)#", $string, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
}
```

Comment: PHP developers that don't use braces make my blood boil

Comment: @Bojangles depends on the coding style. when I don't use braces and I have statements around it, I put newlines around the if instead of braces. But when you write no empty lines it won't be readable...

Comment: Because that's not confusing at all once you have more than 10 lines in a file...

Comment: If you always indent correctly, it's not a big problem to read…

Comment: That was the problem at the company I used to work at `;)`

Comment: That they didn't indent correctly…? there exist also IDE's which can do the reindenting for you.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will do it:

```
if (preg_match('/frame=\s*(\d+)/', $string, $match)) {
    $number = $match[1];
}
```